# SQL query to get a bin with the smallest amount of an item

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, min

I have a Table that looks like this:

```
|Bin    |Item       |Amnt
|-------|-----------|----
|01SIS  |BA0001-BLK |7
|01A1   |BA0001-BLK |1
|01SIS  |BA0001-KAK |1
|01A1   |BA0001-KAK |5
```

and I want to get the Bin with the smallest amount of each Item, like so:

```
|Bin    |Item       |Amnt
|-------|-----------|----
|01A1   |BA0001-BLK |1
|01SIS  |BA0001-KAK |1
```

it looks easy, but grouping is tricky.
does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: This does not appear to be tricky at all.  It appears to be very straight forward.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the lowest number for each item you have as a first step.

```
SELECT Item, MIN(Amnt) AS Amnt
INTO #MinCounts
FROM Table
GROUP BY Item
```

Knowing that, you then inner join that dataset to the original table to eliminate any items that don't match your min counts.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table T
INNER JOIN #MinCounts MC
ON MC.Item = MC.Item
AND MC.Amnt = T.Amnt
```

This will give you duplicates if the "minimum" number matches more than one item.

Comment: You can't use MIN(*). It MUST be a column, in this case I would guess Amnt. I don't know that I would use a temp table for this but it is one way to do it.

Comment: I sped through it a bit too fast, I've made the change. Also, feel free to use a CTE, subquery, or table variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable AS tbl
WHERE tbl.Amnt = (SELECT MIN(Amnt) FROM YourTable Where YourTable.Item = tbl.Item);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Efficient Version for Returning Many Records

I'm going to assume that you are at least using SQL Server 2008 and above.
I believe my version should be very efficient depending on your indexes for returning lots of data. This works by ranking each **Bin** by **Amnt**, then selecting the lowest **Amnt**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,AmntRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Bin ORDER BY Amnt) 
    FROM YourTable
) AS A
WHERE AmntRank = 1 /*Only select lowest Amount for each Bin*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CROSS APPLY` to get the minimum value for each bin in combination with `DISTINCT` to remove the duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       Bin ,
       details.Item ,
       details.Amt
FROM dbo.Data do
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                         Amt,
                         Item
                  FROM    dbo.Data di
                  WHERE   di.Bin = do.Bin
                  ORDER BY  AMT DESC
            ) details
```

Answer (score 0):

This Group by should work

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       Bin ,
       Item ,
       Amt
FROM YourTable do
INNER JOIN (SELECT Bin. MIN(Amnt)Amt FROM YourTable GROUP BY Bin) Tmp
On Tmp.Bin = do.Bin and details.Amt = Tmp.Amt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with mytable as
(
  select '01SIS' as Bin, 'BA0001-BLK' as Item, 7 as Amnt
  union all
  select '01A1'   , 'BA0001-BLK', 1
  union all
  select '01SIS'  , 'BA0001-KAK', 1
  union all
  select '01A1'   , 'BA0001-KAK', 5
)
select top 1 with ties *
from mytable
order by Amnt asc
```